# codeigniter access the result set

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new to codeigniter and have the following code:

```
    $userAuthenticated = $this->Membership_model->userLogin($email, $pass);
```

And in the model, the following is the method:

```
function userLogin($email, $password)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('members');
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

I am facing a problem accessing the $userAuthenticated shown above. It contains the details of the user who tried to login. How can I access the attributes?

Regards,

Comment: **How can I access the attributes** what it means you want to access the information resides in this ?

Comment: Your query should return only 1 record, therefore you should be using ->row() instead of ->result() for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this

```
  return $query->result();
```

with this:

```
  if ( $query->num_rows() == 1 ) { 
  return $query->row(); }
  else { return FALSE; }
```

replace this

```
 $userAuthenticated = $this->Membership_model->userLogin($email, $pass);
```

with this

```
  // check negative condition first
  if( !  $data['userAuthenticated'] = $this->Membership_model->userLogin($email, $pass) ){
  // show no results view 
  $this->load->view( 'wedontknowyouatall', $data );
  } 
  else {
  // we have a result back
  // and we have already passed userAuthenticated into $data 
  // now show result view 
  $this->load->view( 'mysweetviewpage', $data );
 }
```

in the view page you now have access to all the database fields like

```
  echo $userAuthenticated->email ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return $query->row();

if($userAuthenticated ){
login true
}else{
login false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check for the number of rows selected by the query like this:

```
if($userAuthenticated->num_rows() > 0){
     login
}else{
    not login
}
```

else you have to do the loop to get the data selected:

```
foreach($userAuthenticated as $user){
    echo $user->[variable];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

$userAuthenticated->firstname;
$userAuthenticated->email;
$userAuthenticated->pass;

and so on.